# Kafka: Controller 1 epoch 11 fails to send request when changing the mapping in docker port

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am trying to run [confluentinc/cp-kafka](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka) docker image on my system on a port other than `9092` (on port `9000`).

Zookeeper is running successfully on port `2181`.

I ran the following command:

```bash
sudo docker run --name kafka-dev \
-p 9000:9092 \
-e KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1 \
-e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=<INTERNAL_IP>:2181 \
-e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://<INTERNAL_IP>:9000 \
-e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
confluentinc/cp-kafka
```

but when I change the port mapping `9092`, I do not face any errors.

This is the error I am getting:

```
[2023-09-05 11:04:39,429] INFO [RequestSendThread controllerId=1] Controller 1 connected to 192.168.1.170:9000 (id: 1 rack: null) for sending state change requests (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
[2023-09-05 11:04:39,430] INFO [Controller id=1, targetBrokerId=1] Node 1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-09-05 11:04:39,430] INFO [Controller id=1, targetBrokerId=1] Cancelled in-flight UPDATE_METADATA request with correlation id 163 due to node 1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 1ms, elapsed time since send: 1ms, request timeout: 30000ms) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-09-05 11:04:39,431] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=1] Controller 1 epoch 15 fails to send request (type: UpdateMetadataRequest=, controllerId=1, controllerEpoch=15, brokerEpoch=333, partitionStates=[], liveBrokers=UpdateMetadataBroker(id=1, v0Host='', v0Port=0, endpoints=[UpdateMetadataEndpoint(port=9000, host='192.168.1.170', listener='PLAINTEXT', securityProtocol=0)], rack=null)) to broker 192.168.1.170:9000 (id: 1 rack: null). Reconnecting to broker. (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to 1 was disconnected before the response was read
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.sendAndReceive(NetworkClientUtils.java:99)
        at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:256)
        at org.apache.kafka.server.util.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.java:127)
```

Comment: You are missing `KAFKA_LISTENERS` variable. I strongly suggest you use Docker compose, not `docker run`. https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/7.5.0-post/cp-all-in-one-community/docker-compose.yml